# How to record watch command output to a file in gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

I want to record the register changes using watch command in gdb which is like this:

```
(gdb) watch $register-name
```

gdb  stop whenever the register changes in the application and I have to press c to continue debugging. Is there any way to instead of hitting enter for endless time, I just ask gdb to save all the changes in the register to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to press c to continue debugging.

Note that pressing `<Enter>` will repeat previous command (e.g. previous `c`).

> Is there any way to instead of hitting enter for endless time, I just ask gdb to save all the changes in the register to a file?

Sure:

```
(gdb) watch $rax
Watchpoint 2: $rax

(gdb) commands 2
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 2, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>c
>end

# This is to prevent stop after every screen-full of output
(gdb) set height 0

(gdb) set logging on
Copying output to gdb.txt.

(gdb) continue
```

Voila: you now have all the changes in `gdb.txt`